# install System.Net.Http to .net framework 4.0 project

Tags: .net-4.0, nuget-package

I need use AuthenticationHeaderValue for getting token

```
var token = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
```

so I have to install System.Net.Http package but when I install it via package manager console it give that error
what should I do?
what is AuthenticationHeaderValue alternative?

Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly  references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Answer (score 1):

Install System.Net.http version which is compatible to your .Net Framework

Comment: How do you know which one is? Especially the one compatible to the question, that is, .Net Framework 4.0?